# Word for three-dimensional cevian

Tags: 3d

Is there a specific word for three dimensional cevians? I am referring to the line segment from a vertex of a tetrahedron to the opposite face. I have tried looking this up but have not found any results.

Comment: I feel like the word "cevian" will be easily understood in that context.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia, cevians are named after Giovanni Ceva, due to [Ceva's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem).  The theorem does generalize to higher dimensions, and at least one reference to those generalizations ([Landy 1988](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322390)) refers to any line segment connecting a vertex of a tetrahedron to the opposite face as a "cevian" as well.